# Python3 - BeautifulSoup - Get value between two tags, where values between

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have below HTML blocks, that are generated by `pdftotext` using the `-bbox-layout` option:

```
<flow>
<block xMin="21.600000" yMin="86.356000" xMax="178.647000" yMax="116.233001">
    <line xMin="21.600000" yMin="86.356000" xMax="178.647000" yMax="101.833000">
        <word xMin="21.600000" yMin="86.356000" xMax="178.647000" yMax="101.833000">
            My text string located here!</word>
    </line>

</block>
</flow>

[...]
<flow>
<block xMin="223.560000" yMin="323.675000" xMax="345.563500" yMax="339.855500">
    <line xMin="223.560000" yMin="323.675000" xMax="345.563500" yMax="339.855500">
        <word xMin="223.560000" yMin="323.675000" xMax="316.836500" yMax="339.855500">Another string
        </word>
        <word xMin="320.022000" yMin="323.675000" xMax="345.563500" yMax="339.855500">And another!</word>
    </line>
</block>
</flow>
```

Now, I am trying to dynamically parse the above structure, and get each `<block>[...]</block>` content, where the values `xMin` and `xMax` is between two numbers.

Imagine I have below numbers:

```py
areas[0] = (100, 0, 200, 792)
areas[1] = (200, 0, 612, 792)

with open(path_to_html_document) as html_file:
    parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(html_file)
    for (i, area) in enumerate(areas):

        xMinValue, xMaxValue = areas[i][0], areas[i][2]

        block_tags = parsed_html.find_all(
            "block", attrs={"xMin": xMinValue, "xMax": xMaxValue})

        print(block_tags)
```

Above code doesn't return anything, because there are no matching tags. The `find_all()` search for exact matches for `block` tags with the specific numbers - but I am trying to search for `block` tags, where xMin and xMax is:

```
areas[0] is between 100 and 200

areas[1] is between 200 and 612
```

is this possible with BeautifulSoup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code :

```
block_tags = parsed_html.find_all(
            "block", attrs={"xMin": xMinValue, "xMax": xMaxValue})
print(block_tags)
```

TO:

```
block_tags = parsed_html.find_all("block")

for block in block_tags:
    if float(block['xmin']) >= xMinValue and  float(block['xmax']) <= xMinValue:
        print(block)
```

If debug html code `print(parsed_html)`, you will see `html block` all attribute in small letter.

Comment: In the `if float(...` statement, is it supposed to be 2x `xmin` values we are checking against? Not `xMax`?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
parsed_html.select("block")
```

and filt the result with key "xMin" and "xMax".

For example, if you want to get `<block xMin="1" xMax="2"></block>`, you can first get all `block` tags by

```
all_blocks = parsed_html.select("block")
```

And you want to get one of the `block` whose `xMin` is 1 and `xMax` is 2, you can make it like:

```
target = filter(lambda x: x["xMin"] == "1" and x["xMax"] == 2, all_blocks)
```

Comment: Would you mind providing a bit more information? How can this solve my current issue, where I need to get tags where `xMin` and `xMax` is between a set of numbers?

Answer (score 0):

You can select `<block>` with attributes `xMin` and `xMax` with CSS selector `block[xMin][xMax]`. Then you do filtering through list comprehension:

```
data = '''<flow>
<block xMin="21.600000" yMin="86.356000" xMax="178.647000" yMax="116.233001">
    <line xMin="21.600000" yMin="86.356000" xMax="178.647000" yMax="101.833000">
        <word xMin="21.600000" yMin="86.356000" xMax="178.647000" yMax="101.833000">
            My text string located here!</word>
    </line>

</block>
</flow>

<flow>
<block xMin="223.560000" yMin="323.675000" xMax="345.563500" yMax="339.855500">
    <line xMin="223.560000" yMin="323.675000" xMax="345.563500" yMax="339.855500">
        <word xMin="223.560000" yMin="323.675000" xMax="316.836500" yMax="339.855500">Another string
        </word>
        <word xMin="320.022000" yMin="323.675000" xMax="345.563500" yMax="339.855500">And another!</word>
    </line>
</block>
</flow>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

def blocks_min_max(soup, x_min, x_max):
    return [b for b in soup.select('block[xMin][xMax]') if float(b['xmin']) >= x_min and float(b['xmax']) <= x_max]

for b in blocks_min_max(soup, 10, 200):
    print(b.prettify())
```

Prints:

```
<block xmax="178.647000" xmin="21.600000" ymax="116.233001" ymin="86.356000">
 <line xmax="178.647000" xmin="21.600000" ymax="101.833000" ymin="86.356000">
  <word xmax="178.647000" xmin="21.600000" ymax="101.833000" ymin="86.356000">
   My text string located here!
  </word>
 </line>
</block>
```

Comment: Thanks Andrej! However, this gives me the following error: `Unsupported or invalid CSS selector: "block[xMin][xMax]`

Comment: @oliverbj What version of BeautifulSoup are you using? I'm on `beautifulsoup4==4.7.1`